# How can i convert month int to month name in a python dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, monthcalendar

I'm using a pandas dataframe in python and I want to transform an integer between 1 and 12 into an abbreviated month name.

I have a df that prints out like

```
Parcel        Month_sold
Property A      8
Property B      9
Property C      2
```

However, my desired output is:

```
Parcel        Month_sold
Property A      Aug
Property B      Sep
Property C      Feb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = {'Parcel':['Property A','Property B','Property C'],'month_sold':[8,9,2]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)

import calendar
df1['month'] =df1['month_sold'].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[x])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pandas itself provides everything you need.

```
df['Month_sold'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month_sold'], format='%m').dt.month_name().str[:3]
```

This one-liner does not require importing libraries (e.g. `calendar`).